# Comparing two columns in the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns A and B, If A Column have the specific value for Eg: High then the corresponding B Column should contain the Date value.
If A Column have the specific value for Eg: High and the corresponding B Column does not have date value then the cell should be highlighted as Red.

Comment: Use conditional formatting? What's your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ColorColB()

Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim LastRow, i As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet
```

Find the last cell in column A... counts how many rows

```
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Run a loop.. checking if there is nothing in column B then color it red

```
For i = 1 to LastRow

If cells(i, 2) = "" then Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Next i

End sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ashton, still I did not got my answer. I have two columns A and B, If A Column have the specific value "High" then the corresponding cell in B Column should contain the Date (dd/mm/yyyy)value otherwise if date value is not available the cell should be highlighted as Red.